# why my mpi code is running only on one node of cluster?

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing

I'm a beginner in linux and mpi and making clusters .
I'm using linux ubuntu 18.04 and i need to run an mpi code on a cluster .
I made a cluster of tow nodes , just connect them together using a switch and install openssh-server  and mpich on each of them using these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install openssh-server
sudo apt install mpich
```

after that to let them connect each other without password , i generate an rsa key to each on and added it to another node using these commands   :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id {ip of the other node}
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then, i put the hello world code at the same path on each node and compile it and run it :

```
mpicc mpi_hello_world.c -o mpi_hello_world
mpirun -n 4 -hosts manager,worker ./mpi_hello_world
```

where manager and worker and defined at the hosts file .
the output is :

```
Hello world from processor manager, rank 1 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor manager, rank 0 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor manager, rank 3 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor manager, rank 2 out of 4 processors
```

here is my hosts files:
on manager:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 manager
127.0.1.2 worker
::1          ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0      ip6-localnet
ff00::0      ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1      ip6-allnodes
ff02::2      ip6-allrouters
```

on worker :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 manager 
127.0.1.2 worker 
::1          ip6-localhost ip6-loopback 
fe00::0      ip6-localnet 
ff00::0      ip6-mcastprefix 
ff02::1      ip6-allnodes 
ff02::2      ip6-allrouters
```

is there any mistake ?

Comment: a possible explanation is `manager` has more than 4 cores, and mpich default policy is to  pack the nodes first. `mpirun -ppn 2 ...` used to do the trick, but I have not tried it for a while.

Comment: the output still the same. four print statements but the process name is manager in all .

Comment: Are you running `mpirun` on `manager`?

Comment: What does `ssh worker hostname` returns?

Comment: Yes, i'm running it on manager.

Comment: when i run `ssh worker hostname` on manager ,it gives me `manager` 
 and when i run `ssh manager hostname` on worker ,it gives me `worker`
actually i notice the problem , but how can i slove it ?

Comment: Did you swap ip addresses in `/etc/hosts` ?

Comment: yes , here is my hosts files:
on manager:
`127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 manager
127.0.1.2 worker
::1            ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0     ip6-localnet
ff00::0      ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1      ip6-allnodes
ff02::2      ip6-allrouters`
on worker :
`127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 manager
127.0.1.2 worker
::1            ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0     ip6-localnet
ff00::0      ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1      ip6-allnodes
ff02::2      ip6-allrouters`
is there any mistake ?

Comment: you cannot use addresses in the loopback network for real machines: they will all point to the localhost. instead, use addresses in the private networks `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12` or `192.168.0.0/16`

Comment: finally , it worked! . i just changed the ips as you said . thanks a lot :)